# angular js how to validate another form when one form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am using two forms in one page address1 and address2 i am using anugular js validation on submit, how can i validate both forms when button on another form is clicked.

`

Comment: What you tried so far.. Please paste some code here

Comment: You do not give much information, the little you have provided it sounds like you probably should be doing it with just 1 form that wraps both. Either way you could pass the form into a function and check `form.$isValid` but honestly without code you wont get much help.

Comment: You don't even have to pass the form if you give it a name. It should be available as `$scope.formName`.

Comment: @Lex, nice, I am still getting familiar so good to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

called secondform.$submitted on form 1 for validating form 1

```
<div ng-controller="AddressController as Addr">
<div class="row" >
    <div class="  col-sm-5 col-md-6 " >
        <form name="addressForm" valid-submit="checkout()" novalidate  class="form-horizontal col-sm-11 col-md-12" >
           <div class="panel panel-default mar-t">

                <h3 class="panel-heading nomar-t">Billing Address </h3>
                 <div class="space-pad">
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.firstname.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted}" >
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="firstname">First Name:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">  <input type="text" class="form-control " maxlength="50" name="firstname" required value="" placeholder="Enter First Name"ng-model="Address.first_name" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="25" >
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.firstname.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">First Name is required.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.firstname.$error.minlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">First Name is too short.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.firstname.$error.maxlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">First Name is too long.</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.lastname.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted}">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="lastname">Last Name:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"> <input type="text" class="form-control " maxlength="50" name="lastname" style="" required placeholder="Enter Last Name" ng-model="Address.last_name" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="25" />
                     <p ng-show="addressForm.lastname.$error.minlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Last Name is too short.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.lastname.$error.maxlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Last Name is too long.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.lastname.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Last Name is required.</p>
                    </div>
                      </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.address1.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="address1">Address 1:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">    <input type="text" class="form-control " maxlength="100" name="address1" required placeholder="Enter Address"ng-model="Address.address_1"  ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="100" maxlenth="100" >
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.address1.$error.minlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Address is too short.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.address1.$error.maxlength  && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Address is too long.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.address1.$error.required  && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Address is required.</p>
                    </div>
                     </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.address2.$invalid && addressForm.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="reg-firstname">Address 2:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8"> <input type="text" class="form-control " name="address2" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Address 2" ng-model="Address.address_2" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="100" maxlenth="100"></div>
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm.address2.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Address is too short.</p>-->
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm.address2.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Address is too long.</p>-->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.city.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }" >
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="city">City:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control " name="city" placeholder="Enter city" maxlength="50" required placeholder=""ng-model="Address.city" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="50">
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.city.$error.minlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">City Name is too short.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.city.$error.maxlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">City Name is too long.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.city.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">City Name is required.</p>
                    </div>
                           </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.state.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4"  for="reg-firstname">State:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                   <div class="col-sm-8"> <select name="state" class="form-control"ng-model="Address.state_id" required>
                       <option value="" disabled selected>Select State</option>

                           <option value="1">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="2">NewYork</option>
                    </select>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm.state.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Please select a state.</p>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.zipcode.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted}">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="zipcode">Zip Code:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">  <input type="text" class="form-control " maxlength="5" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" name="zipcode" required placeholder=""ng-model="Address.zip_code"  ng-pattern="/^\d{6}$" >
                     <p ng-show="addressForm.zipcode.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Please enter a valid zip code.</p>                
                     <p ng-show="addressForm.zipcode.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Zip code is required.</p>                
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.country.$invalid &&addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4 " for="country">Country:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="country" class="form-control" ng-model="Address.country_id">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Country </option>
                            <option value="1">USA</option>
                        </select></div>
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm.country.$error.required" class="help-block">Please Select a Country</p>--> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="landlinephoneno">Land-Phone no:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control " maxlength="10" name="landlinephoneno"  placeholder="Enter Land-Phone no"ng-model="Address.landline_phone_no"></div>
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm.landlinephoneno.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter a Land line phone no</p>--> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.mobilephoneno.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="mobilephoneno">Mobile no:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">  <input type="text" class="form-control " maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter Mobile no" name="mobilephoneno" required ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="12" placeholder=""ng-model="Address.mobile_phone_no" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]">
                     <p ng-show="addressForm.mobilephoneno.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Please enter a valid mobile number.</p>                
                     <p ng-show="addressForm.mobilephoneno.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Mobile number is required.</p> 

                    </div>
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm.mobilephoneno.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter a mobile number</p>-->
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm.mobilephoneno.$error.maxlenght" class="help-block">Please enter a valid mobile number</p>-->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm.altemail.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }"> 
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="reg-firstname">Email:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">  <input type="text" class="form-control " maxlength="50" name="altemail"  placeholder="Enter Email"ng-model="Address.alt_email">
                   <p ng-show="addressForm.altemail.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
                  </div>

                </div>
                     <div class="form-group ">
                          <lable class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-4">  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="billingAdd" ng-change="checkChange()"> same as shipping address
    </lable>
                     </div>
            <div  >

        </div>
                </div>
               </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <div class="  col-sm-5 col-md-6 address form-horizontal" >
        <form name="addressForm2" valid-submit="checkout()" novalidate class="form-group col-sm-11 col-md-12 mar-t" >

             <div class="panel panel-default ">

                <h3 class="panel-heading nomar-t">Shipping Address </h3>
                <div class="space-pad">
                <div class="form-group " ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.firstname.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted}" >
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="firstname">First Name:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">  <input type="text" class="form-control "  maxlength="50" name="firstname" required value="" placeholder="Enter First Name"ng-model="Address2.first_name" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="25" >
                   <p ng-show="addressForm2.firstname.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">First Name is required.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.firstname.$error.minlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">First Name is too short.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.firstname.$error.maxlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">First Name is too long.</p>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.lastname.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="lastname">Last Name:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                   <div class="col-sm-8"> <input type="text" class="form-control "  maxlength="50" name="lastname" style="" required placeholder="Enter Last Name" ng-model="Address2.last_name" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="25" />
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.lastname.$error.minlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Last Name is too short.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.lastname.$error.maxlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Last Name is too long.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.lastname.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Last Name is required.</p>
                   </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.address1.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="address1">Address 1:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                   <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control " name="address1"  maxlength="100" required placeholder="Enter Address"ng-model="Address2.address_1"  ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="100" >
                   <p ng-show="addressForm2.address1.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Address is required.</p>
                   <p ng-show="addressForm2.address1.$error.minlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Address is too short.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.address1.$error.maxlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Address is too long.</p>
                   </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.address2.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="reg-firstname">Address 2:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control " name="address2"   maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Address 2" ng-model="Address2.address_2" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="100" ></div>
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm2.address2.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Address is too short.</p>-->
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm2.address2.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Address is too long.</p>-->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.city.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }" >
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="city">City:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control " name="city" required placeholder="Enter City" ng-model="Address2.city" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="100">

                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.city.$error.minlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">City Name is too short.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.city.$error.maxlength && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">City Name is too long.</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.city.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">City Name is required.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.state.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="reg-firstname">State:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8"> <select name="state" ng-model="Address2.state_id" required class="form-control">
                       <option value="" disabled selected>Select State </option>
                        <option value="1">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="2">NewYork</option>
                    </select>
                <p ng-show="addressForm2.state.$error.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Please select a state.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.zipcode.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted}">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="zipcode">Zip Code:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                   <div class="col-sm-8"> <input type="text" class="form-control " name="zipcode"  maxlength="6" placeholder="Enter Zip Code"  placeholder=""ng-model="Address2.zip_code"  ng-pattern="/^\d{6}$" required>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.zipcode.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Please enter a valid zip code.</p>                
                     <p ng-show="addressForm2.zipcode.required && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Zip code is required.</p>                
                   </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.country.$invalid &&addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="country">Country:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><select name="country"ng-model="Address2.country_id"  class="form-control">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select your country </option>
                        <option value="1">USA</option>
                    </select></div>
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm2.country.$error.required" class="help-block">Please Select a Country</p>--> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="landlinephoneno">Land-Phone no:</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-8"> <input type="text" class="form-control " name="landlinephoneno"  maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter Land-Phone no" placeholder=""ng-model="Address2.landline_phone_no"></div>
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm2.landlinephoneno.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter a Land line phone no</p>--> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.mobilephoneno.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="mobilephoneno">Mobile no:<span class="redstar">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control " name="mobilephoneno" placeholder="Enter Modil no" maxlength="10" required ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="12" ng-model="Address2.mobile_phone_no" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]">
                    <!--<p ng-show="addressForm2.mobilephoneno.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter a mobile number</p>
                    <p ng-show="addressForm2.mobilephoneno.$error.maxlenght" class="help-block">Please enter a valid mobile number</p>-->
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addressForm2.altemail.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted }">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="reg-firstname">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control " name="altemail"  maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Email"ng-model="Address2.alt_email">
                      <p ng-show="addressForm2.altemail.$invalid && addressForm2.$submitted" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            <div class=" text-right" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " > checkout </button> 

        </div>
                </div>
                 </div>
            </form>
    </div>

</div>
```